# Ubuntu Mate on raspberry Pi stuck on color test screen: first boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi2

I recently downloaded an image from the raspberry Pi website. I flashed that to my SD Card using All of the GUI interfaces shown [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup). As mentioned in the title, I plug the micro ad card into my Pi, and it pops up to a screen with many different colors on it. Nothing else is shown. This is now the 2nd hour it has been on this screen.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what happens when you get stuck on the rainbow screen is that the pi can't find the kernel.img on the sd card. Alternatively, your power supply may be less than 500ma (which is tiny, so this generally isn't the issue).

I would take the following steps:

1. Check the power output from the wall wart you are using to power the
   pi.
2. Stick your card in a windows box and see if `kernel.img` is
   present.
3. Wipe the sd card and give it another go.
4. Try a different sd card in case there is an issue with the card
5. Bang your head against a wall, because I'm out of ideas. It could be a bad pi board :/

There's some pretty good discussion [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55464) with plenty of trouble shooting options that may get you out of a jam if the steps above don't do anything to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that before, but apparently, I have a good power supply, an 8gb class 10 ad card, and I've tried it at least 10 times. Problem: don't have a Windows machine. Is it possible to see kernel.img on a Mac?

Comment: Also, I just looked on my Mac, and found out that there is a file called kernel7.img does that count?